# React does not update State (React-Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have the following setup:

```
  const templates = [
    'dot',
    'line',
    'circle',
    'square',
  ];
  
  const [currentTemplate, setCurrentTemplate] = useState(0);

  const changeTemplate = (forward = true) => {
    let index = currentTemplate;
    index = forward ? index + 1 : index - 1;
    if (index > templates.length - 1) {
      index = 0;
    } else if (index < 0) {
      index = templates.length - 1;
    }
    setCurrentTemplate(index);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Current Template is: ${templates[currentTemplate]}`);
  }, [currentTemplate]);

  useKeypress('ArrowLeft', () => {
    changeTemplate(false);
  });
  useKeypress('ArrowRight', () => {
    changeTemplate(true);
  });
```

This is the useKeypress-Hook is used:

```
  import { useEffect } from 'react';
/**
 * useKeyPress
 * @param {string} key - the name of the key to respond to, compared against event.key
 * @param {function} action - the action to perform on key press
 */
export default function useKeypress(key: string, action: () => void) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function onKeyup(e: KeyboardEvent) {
      if (e.key === key) action();
    }
    window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyup);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyup);
  }, []);
}
```

Whenever I press the left or right arrow key, the function gets triggered. But the `currentTemplate` variable is not changing. It always stays at 0. The `useEffect` is only triggered when I swich the key from left to right or the other way. Clicking the same key twice, does not trigger `useEffect` again, but it should! When changing from right to left, the output is `Current Template is: square` and when changing from left to right, it is `Current Template is: line`. But this never changes. The value of `currentTemplate` always stays `0`.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think the problem might be related to `useKeypress`. You could test this by attaching the change function to buttons - and if this works, it means the fault lies within the `useKeypress`-hook. Could you share the implementation of this hook?

Comment: You were absolutely right! When using to buttons it all worked fine. I included my useKeypress-Hook, but have no idea what could be wrong with it for this use case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `useEffect` inside the `useKeypress` hook.

```
export default function useKeypress(key: string, action: () => void) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function onKeyup(e: KeyboardEvent) {
      if (e.key === key) action();
    }
    window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyup);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyup);
  }, []); //  problem
}
```

The hook is a single `useEffect` with no dependencies. Meaning, it will only fire once. This is a problem for the `action` you are passing into this hook. Whenever the `changeTemplate`-action changes in your component (i.e. on a rerender), the reference to this is not renewed inside of the `useKeypress`-hook.

To solve this, you need to add the `action` to the dependency array of the `useEffect`:

```
export default function useKeypress(key: string, action: () => void) {
  useEffect(() => {
    function onKeyup(e: KeyboardEvent) {
      if (e.key === key) action();
    }
    window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyup);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('keyup', onKeyup);
  }, [action]); //  whenever `action` changes, the effect will be updated
}
```

This is to ensure that the effect is updated whenever the given `action` is changed. After this change, things should be working as expected.

#### Optimalizing:

The `useEffect` will at this point be regenerated for each render, as the `changeTemplate` function will be instanciated for each render. To avoid this, you can wrap the `changeTemplate` with a [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), so that the function is memoized:

```
const changeTemplate = useCallback(
  (forward = true) => {
    let index = currentTemplate;
    index = forward ? index + 1 : index - 1;
    if (index > templates.length - 1) {
      index = 0;
    } else if (index < 0) {
      index = templates.length - 1;
    }
    setCurrentTemplate(index);
  }, 
  // Regenerate the callback whenever `currentTemplate` or `setCurrentTemplate` changes
  [currentTemplate, setCurrentTemplate]
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm! Is there a special benefit from setting `currentTemplate` and `setCurrentTemplate` as dependencies? It works the same way when removing the latter...

Comment: There might be some magic with the `useState` variables, but it is good practice to be explicit when referring to the dependency array of react hooks.

Read more about it here:https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback